# What does it mean space in selection in SCSS

Tags: sass

What does this scss code mean? I mean what's the meaning of space here?

SCSS

```
.animated-title > div div {
  font-size: 12vmin;
  padding: 2vmin 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

this is its html code

```
<div class="animated-title">
  <div class="text-top">
    <div>
      <span>mimicking</span>
      <span>apple's design</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-bottom">
    <div>for the win!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

```
.animated-title > div div
```

above code is targeting every div within another div that is a child of .animated-title, which are:

```
<div>
  <span>mimicking</span>
  <span>apple's design</span>
</div>
```

and

```
<div>for the win!</div>
```

also its not specific to SCSS (sass), its just CSS.